# Fargate returning root domain for presigned S3 URLs - Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-fargate

I have an endpoint on my API that simply uses the AWS SDK to generate a presigned URL for one of our S3 buckets. When hitting the endpoint locally, it works fine every time. However, on the first request to the deployed version (running on Fargate), the first call *always* returns the base S3 URL:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/`

If you hit the API a *second* time, it generates the correct URL, and continues to do so as long as the API is warm. If you wait long enough and try hitting it again, it happens again.

I've verified that the params for generating the URL are correct, even when it generates the wrong URL. I've also added retry logic within the same method, but that continues to return the invalid URL.

Here is the code in question (including the retry):

```
const s3Params = {
            Key: fileName,
            Expires: 120,
            ContentType: contentType,
            ACL: "public-read",
            Bucket: process.env.IMAGE_UPLOAD_BUCKET,
        };

        let uploadUrl = this.awsService.getS3Instance().getSignedUrl("putObject", s3Params);
        // Sometimes this call fails and returns a blank URL
        if (uploadUrl === "https://s3.amazonaws.com/") {
            // Try one more time
            uploadUrl = this.awsService.getS3Instance().getSignedUrl("putObject", s3Params);
        }


        return [uploadUrl, s3Params.Key];
```

Any recommendations for troubleshooting this further?

Comment: What kind of object does `this.awsService.getS3Instance()` return, and how is it constructed?  First instinct is that the constructor might benefit from something like `region: 'ex-ample-1'` because it's discovering the bucket region asynchronously, but too late for the first request.  Second instinct is to argue that this should only make it slower, not make it wrong.  But also... where (which specific region) is the bucket and where is the fargate cluster?

Comment: `this.awsService.getS3Instance()` just returns a constructed instance of the S3 library:

`private s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
 });
`
The bucket discovery could definitely be it, I will try that and report back.

Comment: Looking at this, again, I just noticed that you are not calling `getSignedUrl()` asynchronously.  For that reason, I may have been incorrect when I previously said, *"this should only make it slower, not make it wrong."*  I suspect there's an async attempt made under the hood to discover the bucket region, but it returns at some point after the first synchronous call to `getSignedUrl()` is already done.  Making this async also, with either a callback or a promise, should also fix the issue, I suspect.

Comment: Adding the bucket to the config didn't seem to do anything. I definitely agree that this is an async issue so I'll keep poking at it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use asynchronous callback, because Fargate uses asynchronous credential provider. It is stated in the documentation as follows:

> Note: You must ensure that you have static or previously resolved
>   credentials if you call this method synchronously (with no callback),
>   otherwise it may not properly sign the request. If you cannot
>   guarantee this (you are using an asynchronous credential provider,
>   i.e., EC2 IAM roles), you should always call this method with an
>   asynchronous callback.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Comment: I experienced this same problem and this finally helped. Thanks so much!